# C language-2 dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Below is my code snippet

```
int arr[1][1];
arr[0][0]=55;
arr[0][1]=56;
arr[1][0]=57;
arr[1][1]=58;
printf("\n arr[0,0]=%d",arr[0,0]);
printf("\n arr[0,1]=%d",arr[0,1]);
printf("\n arr[0,2]=%d",arr[0,2]);
```

I get output as
-12
-10
-8

Can someone let me know the meaning of arr[0,0]?

Answer (score 3):

**Q** Can someone let me know the meaning of arr[0,0]?

**A** `arr[0,0]` is equivalent to `arr[0]`.

When you have series of comma separated expressions, the value of the last expression is the value of the entire expression. As an extended example,

`arr[10, 200, 50, 983, 52]` is equivalent to `arr[52]`

Your program needs to be reworked to print an integer, as you are expecting with your use of `%d` in the format specifier.

```
printf("\n arr[0][0]=%d",arr[0][0]);
```

If you want to print `arr[0][1]` and `arr[0][2]`, you need to change the definition of `arr` to

```
int arr[1][3];
```

**Looking at your new code**

Change

```
int arr[1][1];
```

to

```
int arr[2][2];
```

Otherwise, the following lines will show undefined behavior:

```
arr[0][1]=56;
arr[1][0]=57;
arr[1][1]=58;
```

Comment: And, as such, he's getting undefined behavior, since his array has only 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the *comma operator*.  It evaluates to its second operand, so your code is equivalent to:

```
printf("\n arr[0,0]=%d",arr[0]);
printf("\n arr[0,1]=%d",arr[1]);
printf("\n arr[0,2]=%d",arr[2]);
```

This is undefined behaviour in three different ways at once:

- `arr[0]` is not an int (it's an array of int), so printing it with `%d` is not right
- The dimension is `1`, so `arr[1]` and `arr[2]` are out-of-bounds accesses.
- The array is not initialized

To fix this, change to something like:

```
int arr[2][2] = { {1, 2}, {3, 4} };
printf("arr[0][0]=%d\n",arr[0][0]);
printf("arr[1][0]=%d\n",arr[1][0]);
printf("arr[0][1]=%d\n",arr[0][1]);
printf("arr[1][1]=%d\n",arr[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly about the value of expression (0,1):

```
int chk = (0,1);
printf("%d",chk);
```

This is how you can know the value of(0,1). If you want more detail please see: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh.aspx).

---

Therefore `arr[0,1]` is same as `arr[1]`